Driver for Canon TS1900 printer
I am trying to add a printer on a new laptop.  The printer is connected to the laptop via WiFi.  In the past I have managed to effect such an operation relatively easily.  Now when I come to the step where I need to select a printer driver, I find that no driver for the Canon TS9100 printer appears in the list of possible drivers.
It used to be there!
I have done substantial web searching, with no positive results.  The only references to the TS9100 printer driver occur in the context of Windows.
AskUbuntu has several posts about installing printers for Ubuntu, but there is nothing about TS9100. The focus seems to be on PIXMA GM4070, but that does not appear in the list of possible drivers either.
Is there some other driver that I could select that would work?
I am running Ubuntu 24.04.
I have looked at the URL for  "Printer Drivers for Ubuntu 20.04" that was suggested, but the TS9100 driver is not listed there.
It was also suggested that I try the default driver.  How do I go about doing that?  (Apologies if this is a stupid question, but I cannot figure out the answer.)

For the posts that are for the other printer models, go to the website that I believe is the cannon asia website and see if your model is found. If not the exact model, find a very similar model to the one you have (the closest one), download the drivers for that one instead of the one mentioned in the other answer and then follow the basic instructions from the other answer. Does this work?

Sorry for failing to include the Unbuntu version.  I am running Ubuntu 24.04.  I looked at the URL for "Printer Drivers for Ubunti 20.04" but the TS9100 driver is not listed.

The closest one on the Canon website is the TS9140 so download the driver for that model and it should work fine. If it doesn't work, then go with the closest one that's older.

You will need to download and then unzip the downloaded file, then in the terminal, use the cd command to change to the unzipped directory and then run the ./install.sh file. If you encounter a permission issue, then use sudo to run the ./install.sh file. If you encounter a dependency issue, then please post the error, it's not usually difficult to find a newer equivalent that will satisfy the dependency. Also, if you comment back, please begin the reply with @mchid so that I will get a notification.

In addition to installing the drivers, the installer should take care of everything like setting up the printer so that when you're done, you should have a working printer or at least it should be available to add as a printer from your system settings and it should just work from then on out.

a lot of times with network printers you can use the default network printer driver without a specific driver. I am not sure if you have tried that? I think this post is insightful : Printer Drivers for Ubuntu 20.04
It may not be a solution but a start. Also your ubuntu version will help others research the issue.
